# Symfony 2: Check route in TWIG with condition not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to check the current route in the twig template using `{{app.request.get('_route')}}` and it is perfectly showing current `route` name.

**Situation**

I have to make a condition to execute some code if ***route name =  ORDER_FLIGHT*** and I am using the following code in my twig template :

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') == 'ORDER_FLIGHT' %}
    On Search Page
{% else %}
    {{app.request.get('_route')}}
{% endif %}
```

But it is always going in the else part, even when the route is **ORDER_FLIGHT**.

Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: can you print it with `dump`?

Comment: Thank You @Federkun, I am new to symfony. Should I dump it in the twig template?

Comment: yeah `{{ dump(app.request.get('_route')) }}`

Comment: it is showing `STRING(12) "ORDER_FLIGHT"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you can get route in request.attributes, like this:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_route')
```

Comment: could you please explain how do I use this with IF-ELSE condition for specific route?

Comment: In this case, your condition code seems fine. I have a similar condition in my project and works fine.
`{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'DistributorRead' %}`